# How get ArrayList from RecyclerView.Adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm beginner (and french), i have my `MainActivity` class and i use recyclerview with an adapter and it's work but now i want to call this arrayList (Notes) in my MainActivity

```
ArrayList<Note> Notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(Strings);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

from onBindViewHolder method from MyAdapter class :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mButton.setText(Strings[position]);
    //it work

    Integer couleur = Notes.get(position).getCouleur();
    //i want to use Notes from my MainActivity for get a color
}
```

thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Add one more parameter to the constructor of RecyclerView inherited class and... Assign the value to arraylist class variable of class RecyclerView. Something like

```
....
....class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView....
{
List<xyz> arrayList;
....
public MyRecyclerView(...,ArrayList<xyz> arrayList)
{
this.arrayList=arrayList;
}
```

And use `this.arrayList` whereever you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer and i understand what does this code but i first i found this :

```
public class RecyclerView extends ViewGroup implements ScrollingView, NestedScrollingChild {
public RecyclerView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}
```

and i can't modify the code.
Second my arraylist use a bdd (this second code is in my MainActivity)

```
public NotesBDD noteBDD = new NotesBDD(this);
ArrayList<Note> Notess = noteBDD.ConstruireNotes();
    for (Note n : Notess){
        Notes.add(n);
    }
```

It's possible to use non-static methods from an other class ?

Comment: you should post it as a coment, not an answer